# How can I see the response to an HTTP request made from the main process in an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, http, electron, wireshark

I have an Electron app that makes an HTTP request in the main process that is erroring. I want to figure out what's going wrong but I can't figure out any way to see the actual response of the request. I'm using a google api library and I can't figure out how to inspect it directly. I was hoping there'd be a way to view HTTP requests like the newtork tab in chrome devtools. When unning the program with `electron --inspect-brk` the error only prints the my shell console and not the devtools console, so that's of no use either. I tried downloading wireshark but I'm not very familiar with it and haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: You can track your main process error on terminal by using console output

Comment: you are making the request on your main not in renderer so it can't be shown at chrome devtools or so.

Comment: @tpikachu unfortunately the console output isn't expanded enough for me to be able to see the full response.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send your results object to the devtools you *could* use webContents.send in the backend and ipcRenderer in the front.

In the backend:

```
yourBrowserWindowVariable.webContents.send('debugging', httpRequestResults)
```

In the frontend:

```
  <script>
    require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('debugging', (event, message) => {
      console.log('debug message', message)
    })
  </script>
```

Here's the reference in the electron docs:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to get a hold of the actual error. The google api seems to catch it and print it to the console so I have no way of intercepting it.

Comment: If it's logging to the console of your main thread you could install something like Winston and configure to write to disk and then feed your console logging to winston

Comment: Here's an example I found (not mine) that does what I'm talking about. I use something similar and it's very helpful. https://gist.github.com/spmason/1670196